# php prev next button from mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

trying to accomplish the following in PHP instead of the javascript option here, [create previous next button for iframe pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924715/create-previous-next-button-for-iframe-page).

And the array should come from mysql.

can get the array printed as follows to work with the javascript example given replacing the

```
var pages=new Array();
```

with:

```
<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT linkscore, link FROM site_name"))

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

printf("pages[%s]='%s'\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

?>
```

All nice so far but i still need to remove javascript completely.
and i can't get any to work.
Basic idea is

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT link FROM site_name ORDER BY linkscore ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
printf("%s\n", $row[0];

$nextpage = next($row);
<a href="<?php echo "$nextpage" ?>" target="myiframe">Foo</a
```

Have tried many, many variations to this theme, and sure i came close many times, but my basic grasp of PHP is too little to see where i go wrong.
most examples on the net also point to the obvious javascript, probably the best choice but i can not use javascript.

much obliged

Comment: _"and i can't get any to work."_ what isn't working? any errors?

Comment: "any" means all the things i have tried in the last few days. errors would be nice, at least i know where i do something wrong....  the main problem i guess is that i can't catch the array output for further processing

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **Object oriented style**.

Change

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

to

`$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)`

And, Here echoing `$nextpage` will print **$nextpage**. So, change your line to.

```
<a href="<?php echo $nextpage; ?>" target="myiframe">Foo</a>
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT linkscore, link FROM site_name"))

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))

printf("pages[%s]='%s'\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

?>

<?
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT link FROM site_name ORDER BY linkscore ASC");
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
printf("%s\n", $row[0];

$nextpage = next($row);
<a href="<?php echo $nextpage; ?>" target="myiframe">Foo</a>

?>
```

Comment: using     $nextpage = next($row);     is the last thing i was trying, not so sure now actually if that is what i need to keep on processing to the next page, kind of the thing i am looking for is     $next = $current_index + 1;

Comment: See, there are many way to go to next page. But, you should not use *Procedural style* when you are using *Object Oriented style* @randallrandall

Comment: my guess is you are most likely right on this one, but there is not single complete example i could find for what i am trying to achieve here, so am mixing and matching the various snippets i can find trying to learn and understand